# Install wizard flickering dialog: "Wired Network - Disconnected - You are now offline"

Tags: internet-connection, offline

I'm installing a fresh copy of Ubuntu Linux version 11.10.  When going through the install wizard, there is a black popup in the top right hand corner of the screen that keeps flickering randomly and says "Wired Network Disconnected - you are now offline".  When the popup goes away, the network triangular looking icon in the system tray starts flashing like the network is good.  Yet, when I get to the "Preparing to Install Ubuntu" screen, it says, "For best results, ensure that this computer is...".  There are two check marks (meaning it was okay), but the 3rd option has an "X" (meaning something is wrong) not a check mark, and says "is connected to the internet", which tells me it's still not connected.

The reason I'm concerned here is due to my last question.  When Ubuntu installed the first time, it wasn't connected to the internet and didn't download my Dell Inspiron 1100 drivers, and therefore my screen resolution was all messed up.

I plugged the ethernet cable directly into the laptop.  So I'm not using a wired connection.  That ethernet cable was previously connected to a computer that had access to the internet so I know that port on the router is good.  How can I troubleshoot this connection issue?

Comment: I've done quite a bit of troubleshooting today.  I have a feeling my network card is bad on this old laptop, but I don't know how to confirm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My network card is bad.  That's why I couldn't connect.